# How to use a named capture group in VS code Find/Replace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, nsregularexpression

In the vs code find/replace editor widget, I'm using a named capture group `(?<end>.*\s*)`.  I'm then using `${end}`in the replace but its just putting the literal text there instead of the captured contents.  The unnamed capture groups are working as expected.

My regular expression works fine in Visual Studio 2019, but I'm not sure how to tweak the named capture group syntax for VS code.

Comment: because VSC != Visual Studio, one is written in JavaScript the other in C++, in VSC use numeric group references like `$1`

Comment: @rioV8 - yep, I've understood that.  In both VSC and Visual Studio, the $1 (ie unnamed group) syntax works. I'm specifically asking how to write the named group syntax for VSC.  The Javascript documentation shows how to write it in javascript code (e.g. `${match.groups.firstname}`) but I'm not sure how to write it in the replace window in VSC.

Comment: can you give a link of this `Javascript documentation`

Comment: @rioV8 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges

Comment: in which version of Node is the supported and which version of Node is used by VSC

Comment: @rioV8 thank you THANK YOU for explaining it's $1 and not \1.

Answer (score 9):

vscode does not support named capture groups in the replacement, see and **upvote** [Use regular expressions in Visual Studio: Named capture groups](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127657).

Also see a previous issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88793 that failed due to lack of upvotes.

Comment: Wow! I thought I'd gone crazy and forgotten how RegEx worked.

Comment: Note: You can still put named groups in the regex itself - it's just that the replacement field only supports `$1`, `$2` and they'll still get populated even if you use `(?<name>[a-z]+)` for the regex.

Comment: ticket is closed, so thumbs up reaction is disabled. the ticket is in the backlog though?

Comment: This is now a backlog candidate: [Regex Find/Replace with named capture groups](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195724)

Comment: And the issue needs 5 more votes.